# Multiple inheritance: second base class constructor requirements leak to first base class constructor

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to inherit from 2 base classes.

The first base class (`Base1`) constructor takes no arguments:

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

The second base class (`Base2`)  constructor takes one argument, `id`:

```
class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        ...
```

In my derived class I attempt to call each base class constructor in turn:

```
class Deriv(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base1, self).__init__()
        super(Base2, self).__init__("hello world")
```

This fails with the following error:

```
    super(Base1, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

How can I correctly call each base-class constructor with its correct list of arguments?

Here is an exemplar app which reproduces the error I am experiencing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

class Deriv(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base1, self).__init__()
        super(Base2, self).__init__("hello world")

def main():
    Deriv()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 17, in main
    Deriv()
  File "./test.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(Base1, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Comment: `super()` is used for **cooperative inheritance** and not for direct invocation. The second argument is **not** the class to target, it is the **current** class to skip. Unless you know exactly how you want to muck with the MRO, don't use anything other than `super()` or `super(Deriv, self)`.

Comment: Either use `Base1.__init__(self)` and `Base2.__init__('hello world')`, **or** have your base classes use `super().__init__()`, where you make sure to call the next class in the chain cooperatively and take into account that `object.__init__()` does not take any arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you! I'll read up on cooperative inheritance. If you are so inclined, I'll gladly accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood what `super()` does. `super()` takes the `__mro__` method resolution order attribute (a sequence) from type of `self`, then finds the position of the first argument in that sequence, then starts searching **past** that point.

For your case `Deriv.__mro__` is:

```
(<class '__main__.Deriv'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and `super(Base1, self)` will start searching for the `__init__` method on the next object, here `Base2`, and `super(Base2, self)` would find `object`. The error is raised because `Base2.__init__` must take an `id` argument, but `super(Base1, self).__init__()` doesn't provide that argument.

You want to use cooperative inheritance instead, and pass arguments the call chain:

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = id
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Deriv(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("hello world")
```

If you must address base classes directly, then don't use `super()`, and call the unbound methods directly instead:

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

class Deriv(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        Base1.__init__(self)
        Base2.__init__(self, "hello world")
```

Comment: I tried to implement what you've suggested here but whilst I could get it to work on my basic example app, when I tried to do the same in my "real" app, I couldn't get it to work. The edits required to my question would invalidate much of what you've written here, so I thought it best to ask another question. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745442/multiply-inherit-from-qwidget-and-another-base-class)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong first arguments to `super`:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Deriv, self).__init__()
    super(Base1, self).__init__("Hello world")
```

Note, though, that this only works because `Base1.__init__` itself does not use `super`, because if it did, it would attempt to call `Base2.__init__`, as that is the next method in the MRO of the original object.

The first argument to `super` tells you *after* which class in the MRO to start looking for the desired attribute.

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in adapting my "real" code to follow the fixes suggested here (which admittedly *do* fix my test code). I have posted another question as the edits required would be sufficiently large as to invalidate your answer, or at least cause confusion as the original question would be so different. Please see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745442/multiply-inherit-from-qwidget-and-another-base-class)