# Multiply inherit from QWidget and another base class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to create a `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget` derived widget, whilst at the same time inherit from another base class, `Base`.

Inheriting from `Base` causes an error when calling the `QWidget` constructor, saying I never provided the arguments which `Base` requires.

This is how I attempt to call the `QWidget` and `Base` constructors:

```
class Deriv(QtWidgets.QWidget, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        Base.__init__(self, "hello world")
```

The error I'm getting says:

```
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Is it possible to inherit from both `QWidget` and `Base`, and if so, how do I call their respective constructors correctly?

Here is an exemplar app which reproduces the error I am experiencing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

class Deriv(QtWidgets.QWidget, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        Base.__init__(self, "hello world")

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    d = Deriv()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./test.py", line 18, in main
    d = Deriv()
  File "./test.py", line 11, in __init__
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Note that if I **only inherit from `QWidget`** (so just remove everything referring to `Base`), then the code works

```
class Deriv(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.show()
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit; you need to pass `self.id` as an argument to `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__`.

Comment: `QWidget` doesn't take an id argument. This is the error: `TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'`

Comment: @chepner I've updated the question to show that passing nothing to `QWidget` works, but only when I don't inherit from anything else

Comment: `QTWidgets.QWidget` apparently uses `super`, so if you have additional base classes, then their `__init__` methods get called *from* `QTWidgest.QWidget.__init__`, even if you didn't start out by calling `super`. (I can post an answer to that effect once I track down the source code of `QTWidgets`.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters `QtWidgets.QWidget` does take a parent, but it defaults to `None` - I have removed it for brevity - adding it back in makes no difference afaics

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I think [Why is super used so much in PySide/PyQt?](//stackoverflow.com/q/23981625)  looks relevant here. I'm not that familiar with the PyQt5 structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__` itself uses `super` to call `__init__`. With your single inheritance case, the MRO consists of three classes: `[Deriv, QtWidgets.QWidget, object]`. The call `super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__` would call `object.__init__`, which doesn't expect any additional arguments.

In your multiple inheritance example, the MRO looks like

```
[Deriv, QtWidgets.QWidget, Base, object]
```

which means *now* the call `super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__` refers not to `object.__init__`, but `Base.__init__`, which *does* require an additional argument, leading to the error you see.

Comment: As suggested in one of the answers in my other question, I tried doing `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)` rather than using `super`, but this doesn't seem to work either

Comment: No, it doesn't, because even though *you* aren't calling `super`, `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__` *does* (or at least, I assume so, based on the observed behavior). The rule with `super` is that *every* class involved has to use it, or none of them can.

Comment: Confirmed in the documentation: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#cooperative-multi-inheritance

Comment: The corollary to that rule is that you need to pass on *every* argument your call to `__init__` receives to the super call, because you don't know which ones are expected by calls further up the chain.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the advice on passing on all arguments. I have much to learn!!

Comment: (The exception to the corollary is that if you are the "root" class for a particular method, then you can omit the arguments that are specific to your "branch" of the inheritance tree. However, `object` is always the root for `__init__`, so all you can do is tolerate unexpected arguments and pass them on.)

Comment: Clarification of my corollary: if you are the root class for a method, they you yourself do not need to use `super`; the linearization algorithm that computes the MRO guarantees that every descendent of a class appears *before* that class. If you are a root class that adds an argument to a method like `__init__`, you still have to call `super().__init__` yourself, but you don't have to pass on your custom argument. (In fact, you *cannot* pass it on, because otherwise it will eventually be passed to `object.__init__`--remember, you have to pass on other's arguments--which will choke on it.)